# Qual o plural correto de modem?

Tags: número-gramatical

O plural correto de modem é modems ou modens?

Fiquei na dúvida pois é uma sigla da junção das palavras modulador e demodulador.

Comment: Me fiz essa mesma pergunta, mas sobre a palavra `query`, que no plugin em inglês é `queries`. Mas acho que sendo portugues vou concordar com a resposta e escrever `querys` quando usado no portugues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pelo fato de a palavra "modem" vir do inglês, o plural seria "modems", como atestado no [CRPC](http://www.clul.ul.pt/pt/investigador/183-reference-corpus-of-contemporary-portuguese-crpc) (Corpus de Referência do Português Contemporâneo):

```
modems  99 resultados  
modens   0 resultado
```

(Dito isto, pode ser que em 10 anos "modem" seja reanalisado como palavra portuguesa, comummente pluralizado como "modens".)

Comment: Como se consulta o CRPC para obter os resultados indicados?

Comment: @AméricoTavares A página do CRPC → (Platform CQPweb) → CRPC v2.3 POS fine-grained ([aqui](http://alfclul.clul.ul.pt/CQPweb/crpcfg15/)). O POS significa "parts of speech", e o corpus admite por exemplo consultas como `{contemplação}` com resultados dando todas as infleções de `contemplação`, "contemplação" e "contemplações". (Mas parece que "modems" não é detectado como o plural de "modem"...)

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu esclarecimento.

Comment: Obrigado amigo :D

Comment: *Mas parece que "modems" não é detectado como o plural de "modem"* não entendi, então temos 99 resultados para *mode**m**s* e afinal o plural é *mode**n**s*?

Comment: @JorgeB. Não, o corpus não detecte nenhum plural para _modem_, provavelmente porque _modens_ tem nenhum resultado. Suspecto, que o corpus não reconhece plurais irregulares.

Comment: @Earthliŋ estranho que aqui em Portugal dizemos o modem e os modems. Nunca modens.

Comment: O correto não seria pluralizar conforme o português "dois modens" ou manter no singular em inglês "dois modem"?